# Convert String to Date. can Date.parse be used?

Tags: java, string, date, parsing, csv

I am trying to read a line from a file, however, I keep getting an error saying:

```
Incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Date.
```

How can I fix this?

```
String[] attributes = csvString.split(",");
teamName = attributes[0];
result = attributes[1];
date = (attributes[2]);
opponent = attributes[3];
attendance = Integer.parseInt(attributes[4]);
```

I also tried `date = Date.parse(attributes[2]);`, which did not work.

The file looks as follows:

```
Kronos United,2-3,16/05/2011,Dedfield United,2829
```

Comment: This appears to be `Java` for those wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are representing a date, not a specific instant in time, you should represent the match's date as a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instance, rather than an obsolete and poorly-name [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) instance.

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(text, df);
```

If you can, stick with `LocalDate` throughout your program, and avoid the deprecated `Date` class. If you need to interoperate with some other library that requires a `Date`, you can convert it, but you have choose the target time zone and time of day, which isn't included in the data you are parsing.

Comment: ``Date`` class is not deprecated, just the methods used to format and parse date strings are: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: @AtomHeartFather That's true, the class as a whole isn't `@Deprecated`; it still functions correctly as a parallel to `Instant`. But it is deprecated in the normal sense of having a preferred replacement.

Comment: agreed. I used ``Date`` in my answer because the OP was already using that legacy API.

Comment: @erickson  **This still does not allow me read a date taken from a line in a file and convert it to a String. Has it got something to do with my getter and setter. I also adjusted the code to set attribute 2 could this be the problem.**

Comment: @erickson     ' LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(attributes[2]);        private LocalDate date;


    public LocalDate getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    
    DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/mm/yyyy"); '

Comment: @RichKid In your `DateTimeFormatter`, the pattern should use "MM", not "mm". "mm" would stand for minute, not month. Also, you are not using the `DateTimeFormatter` when you parse the date like I showed. Even though it has "formatter" in the name, it is used for parsing too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

In your example, that should do the trick:

```
String dateString = "16/05/2011";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
```

don't forget to

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
```

Comment: @RichKid The example above shows you how to get a ``Date`` object from a ``String``. The ``DateFormat`` instance can be reused to convert the subsequent strings. What exactly is it that's not working?

Answer (score 0):

What is the datatype of your attribute `date`. Is it date or string? It must be string to read first from csv and then convert to date.

```
String date = attributes[2];
```

And then later convert it to date using `SimpleDateFormat` class.